# In helm, can I change the release name of a deployed release?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Helm to upgrade my k8s environment and I'm wondering,
if I can change the release name of a deployed release using the upgrade command (or any other way)?

**example:**

```
helm upgrade --set image.tag='12.55.6-2' zk-chart /path/to/helm/files
```

So that **zk-chart** will change to **new-zk-chart**, without downtime so I don't want to delete the release and create it again.

Comment: I don't think it allows us to change the chart name during upgrade, we may have to remove old one and install the new one.

Comment: This is what I did eventually

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this.

There is a open [request](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1809) for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue asking for renaming a deployed release but it has been [closed as WONTFIX](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1809#issuecomment-467985478).

> Closing this as a wontfix as the effort and risk involved to rename the rendered resources without causing downtime for the application is incredibly high. Given the time investment and risks involved, it's probably not worth the time to consider implementing a vanity name change.
>
> We'd still love to see someone pick this up as a plugin! If that plugin seems like a workable solution then we can consider absorbing that into the core Helm codebase. Thanks!